# What is Ansible equivalent to Salt's top file?

Tags: ansible, salt-stack

I'm trying to merge from Salt to Ansible.
What is Ansible equivalent to Salt's top file?

Answer (score 1):

In Ansible you build [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html), put your hosts into groups and then you run playbooks, that will bring your hosts to the desired state (e.g. ensure that software is installed, files are present, etc) on those groups. Note that there is no agent software with Ansible, it uses SSH to do things on remote hosts,

Comment: Just surfing on the single answer. Over a few years, I have developed my own taste in Ansible inventory (using yaml rather than ini notation, etc.). It is under my https://github.com/cbugk/ansible-postgresql-demo . Gist of it is to use directories to glue unrelated configurations per group or host (just like having /etc/foo.d for multiple configuration files). It is an amalgam of several lost in search history Stackoverflow answers. I highly suggest GeerlingGuy's youtube playlist for Ansible to anyone looking for an introduction.